# VBA - runtime error 52

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I'm getting the error

> run time error 52, Bad file name or number

while using `FileCopy` to copy local file to sharepoint.

I follow the [document from microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231024(v=vs.60).aspx) and the file path and the file name several times but could find the error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

Dim UploadToSharepoint As Boolean

Dim SharePointLib As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim folderPath As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object
Dim copyPath As String
Dim copyFilePath As String

folderPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
myPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName
MsgBox "This is the folderPath" & folderPath 'C:\Users\username\Desktop
MsgBox "This is the filepath" + myPath 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\testing.xlsm

SharePointLib = "Z:\Test Folder - New Format\"
copyPath = folderPath + "\copyPath\"
MsgBox "The copyPath is = " & copyPath 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\copyPath\

If Not FolderExists(copyPath) Then
    FolderCreate (copyPath)
End If

MsgBox "The file will be uploaded to this address: " + SharePointLib 'Z:\Test Folder - New Format\

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs copyPath & "testing.xlsm"
Call FileCopy(copyPath & "testing.xlsm", SharePointLib)

Exit Sub

loadFailed:
UploadToSharepoint = False

End Sub
```

I copy the path from window explorer after I map the drive to the SharePoint Site.

[image: drive]

**Update**

Map the drive and get the new Path `Z:\Test Folder - New Format`, but still hit run time error 52

Comment: It seems that this is the same as the previous question you asked, the path should be including the file name. However I'm not familiar with sharepoint, not sure if this is the only problem.

Comment: Hi, I did included the file name this time `Call FileCopy(copyPath & "testing.xlsm", SharePointLib)` and I check the file does exist

Comment: You are trying to copy to the SP URL, not to a folder. You either need to copy to the unc path of your SP's folder library like \\spserver\lib\files or use a SP Web service to upload the file

Comment: The `SharePointLib` should include the filename, too.

Comment: @LocEngineer Hi, I had update my question. Am I doing it wrngly? by copying the SP path from window explorer?

Comment: @newacc2240 Hi, It does include the filename, just I did not show in the question

Comment: You SP path in explorer is surely not `https://company.com/sites/`, is it? If it is mapped, it has a drive letter, let's say S:\. Then you need to copy to `"S:\testing.xlsm" - make sure to give a fuill path including filename as the copy destination.

Comment: @ChingChongPa "*just I did not show in the question*": you should always keep your question up to date if you made changes so everybody can see the actual state.

Comment: I had similar problem, Once I had to download attachments from outlook email and save it to One Drive folder, it won't let me do it. as once I put the file there it is not just pasted , it is synced.

Comment: I would use `ThisWorkbook`instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, to be safe

Comment: your `copyPath` contains a double \\ in the middle

Comment: @Peh, Hi sorry that was on purpose. However, the path format is the same, just the naming for the subfolders are different.
@PatrickHonorez Thanks for the suggestion, I will change to `ThisWorkBook`. That double \\ was typo, I already double checked the codes.

Comment: @LocEngineer I found [this regarding to mapping drive to sharepoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpmQORJDy-U). I think this is what you mean. I will change my path and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy moly, thanks for the help guys, @newacc2240 was right. I found out the problem after looking at this example.

`FileCopy "C:\Source\test.txt", "C:\Destination\test.txt"
'Result: Copies file from "C:\Source" to "C:\Destination"`

So for my just need to add my file name to the `SharePointLib`.

Previously I assumed that it would copy the file from the source to the destination with the file name attached, which cause me to stress up for hours.